# How to run GimpShop on Lion

Tags: macos, applications

I've just downloaded GimpShop and wanted to run it on Lion.
So I've copied the app to the Applications folder and started it.
It starts, I can see it's doing something with cache and bam.. it goes away. The only thing left is X11 window with bash prompt.
I've tried closing the X11 app and running it again... nothing.
Is there any way I could start GimpShop on Lion?

Thanks

EDIT:
There's something wrong with font caching or immediately after fonts are cached.
If I remove the font cache directory it will go through the process of caching again and will close immediately after it [or in the middle, hard to tell].
I can see few files inside. If they stay there and I will try to start GimpShop again it will close immediately.

EDIT2:
So I've followed [these instructions](http://www.strayprocess.com/blog/gimpshop-snow-leopard), but I'm still getting an error:

```
bash-3.2$ ./Gimp 
/Applications/Gimpshop.app/Contents/Resources/init: line 7: dev/null: No such file or directory
Fontconfig warning: no <cachedir> elements found. Check configuration.
Fontconfig warning: adding <cachedir>/usr/X11/var/cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
Fontconfig warning: adding <cachedir>~/.fontconfig</cachedir>
/Applications/Gimpshop.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 17: open-x11: command not found
Unable to find application named 'XDarwin'
2012-01-17 00:39:24.040 defaults[74566:507] 
The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleLanguages) does not exist
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Gimpshop.app/Contents/Resources/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libfontconfig.1.dylib requires version 15.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 10.0.0
bash-3.2$
```

Any tips?

Comment: The log shows that Gimpshop tries to call a library in /opt/local/lib which tends to imply that the app was built sing Macports - where did you get GimpShop from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gimpshop is not maintained anymore.
Currently there are no differences between Gimp and Gimpshop, as from Gimp 2.7 you can run it in single window mode.
There's a Gimp 2.8 version available for Lion here: http://gimp.lisanet.de/Website/Download.html

Answer (score 0):

Lots of changes were made in Lion. This could be why you are having issues. However, They do suggest that you use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install GIMPShop. This might help you install it on Lion.

Resources:

- [GIMPShop Instructions (from their website)](http://www.macports.org/)
- [gimpshop on osx lion (a thread from Mac Forms)](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-operating-system/248939-gimpshop-osx-lion.html#post1289302)

Comment: There's no GimpShop on mac ports. Also the Mac Forums thread seems not connected to the problem.

Comment: https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/graphics/gimp2/Portfile - Gimp 2 is the same thing as GimpShop. I know, I installed both yesterday and they were both called Gimp 2 once installed.